# mypy error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module

Tags: python, mypy

I am trying to set MYPYPATH to find a library located in another directory. I am importing a function like this:

```
from my_module import my_function
```

The file structure:

```
function
|__lib1
|  |__lib2
|     |__my_module.py
|__function1
   |__src
      |__index.py  <-- this is the file where my_module is imported
```

The file structure has to be like this because these are AWS Lambdas (`lib1` is the Lambda layer here).

I am using the following tox configuration:

```
skipsdist = True
envlist = mypy

[testenv]
deps = -r requirements.txt

[testenv:mypy]
commands = mypy --namespace-packages -p function -p test
```

I tried setting:

`setenv = MYPYPATH = './function/lib1/lib2'`

`setenv = MYPYPATH = './function/lib1/lib2/my_module.py'`

as well as

`mypy_path = 'function/lib1/lib2'`

`mypy_path = 'function/lib1/lib2/my_module.py'`

I tried full path instead of relative path as well.

However, I'm still getting the same error: `error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named my_module`.

This is not a tox issue, as running `mypy --namespace-packages -p function -p test` alone produces the same error.

Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: It is always a good idea to add the command that led to an error. For tox related problems please include the output for `tox -rvv`. You have a very special project setup. It would be much easier to help you when you create a dummy repo with above files/folders, so anybody trying to help you can try it locally.

Comment: I edited the initial post - the issue lies in mypy configuration itself, not tox.

Comment: maybe you should add `/full/path/to/lib2` instead of relative path

Comment: I tried full path, but it did not help

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?